# C struct, incomplete field type

Tags: c, struct

A snippet of my struct declaration:

```
struct record{
    char type[4];
    uint32_t data_size;
    uint32_t flags;
    uint32_t id;
    uint32_t revision;
    uint16_t version;
    uint16_t unknown;
    uint8_t *data;
};

struct group;

union subgroup_record{
    int type;
    struct group subgroup;
    struct record record;
};

struct record_list{
    union subgroup_record subgroup_record;
    struct record_list *next;
};

struct group{
    char type[4];
    uint32_t group_size;
    uint8_t label[4]; // depends on group_type
    int32_t group_type;
    uint16_t stamp;
    uint16_t unknown1;
    uint16_t version;
    uint16_t unknown2;
    struct record_list record_list;
};

struct group_list{
    struct group group;
    struct group_list *next;
};

struct plugin{
    struct record header;
    struct group_list top_groups;
};
```

The compiler gives me this error:

```
error: field ‘subgroup’ has incomplete type
```

Forward declaring the struct didn't help, typedef'ing the struct and changing the declarations also didn't help and I'd rather not have pointers everywhere (for a beginner the allocating and freeing memory is a bit scary)

Any solution for this?

Thanks!

Comment: _Side note:_ In `subgroup_record` there is `int type`, but this should probably be `char type[4]` to be compatible with the `type` definitions in the other `union` members [or vice versa]. Not critical [or wrong], just an FYI/IMO ...

Comment: `struct record_list record_list;` --> `struct record_list *record_list;`  Add `*`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a circular recursive definition.

The type `struct group` contains the type `struct record_list`, which contains the type `union subgroup_record`, which contains the type `struct group`

A type cannot contain itself.

Comment: Nice answer, however, I would consider, maybe adding an example that resolves the issue by using pointers instead of the actual types...?

Comment: @Myst You can add you own answer if you think that is important.

Comment: I think that having one good answer is better for future readers. Yours is already good enough for anyone encountering the issue (hence, I upvoted it). The comment was both a suggestion and for future readers to implement in their code.